# Importing Json using DocumentDB Data Migration tool gives "Error while fetching page of documents code: 400" in CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

Hi I am trying to import a Json file created using mongoexport into CosmosDB. I am using the DocumentDB migration tool which passes successfully and imports the collection into cosmos. When i try looking at the collection through cosmos DB i get the error code

> Error while fetching page of documents:
>    {"code":400,"body":"Command find failed: Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.."}

I am expecting the document to be view-able through Cosmos DB but am not sure why i am receiving this error code and am not able to see the entry.

The Json string i used ...

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c5310e8dcaf3245045f5b13"
},

"Name": "Azure",
"Description": "CosmoDB",
"CurrentStatus": true,
"SObject": "\"\"",
"TheOption": ["5c5431f2dcrf34504525b14"],
"Settings": {
    "A": "Patched",
    "B": 100.0
},
"OtherKey": "ABC"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing data to a Mongo API account using Data Migration Tool.

In the [official Data Migration Tool article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/import-data), it states that:

> Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB - The Data Migration tool doesn't
>   currently support Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB either as a source
>   or as a target.

Also:

> If you want to migrate the data in or out of collections in Azure
>   Cosmos DB, refer to How to migrate MongoDB data a Cosmos database with
>   Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB for instructions

So you need to follow the [MongoDB migration instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/dms/tutorial-mongodb-cosmos-db?toc=/azure/cosmos-db/toc.json).

You can use the Data Migration Tool if the destination Cosmos DB account is SQL (Core) or Tables API accounts as stated in the docs.