# Error while fetching page of documents in Azure CosmosDB Portal

Tags: mongodb, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

So I'm using Microsoft's Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core api to connect to my Cosmos DB from my .Net Core app.

Everything is working fine in that I can create, edit, and get documents, as well as create a new database or collection. If I create a database or collection using the DocumentDB.Core api, I can see them in my azure portal. However, when I create documents, I can not see them. Whenever I try to load my documents, I get this error a number of times equal to the number of documents I have.

```
Error while fetching page of documents {"code":400,"body":"Command find failed: Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.."}
```

I know I have existing records tho because if I save the Id I get back on creation, I can then look it up using the DocumentDB.Core api.

Here is my model that I am passing:

```
public class Api
{
    public Api()
    {
        Client = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }


    public ExpandoObject Client { get; set; }

}
```

NOW, before I switched to DocumentDB.Core, I was using MongoDB.Driver, and this was my model:

```
public class Api
{
    public Api()
    {
        Client = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }


    [BsonElement("client")]
    public ExpandoObject Client { get; set; }

}
```

Using MongoDB.Driver, and the above model, I was able to see my data in the azure portal.

Is there a reason why I cannot see data in the Azure CosmosDB portal using Microsoft's own tool for it? Am I missing a property? The only thing I notice that is different is that using MongoDB.Drive, my id was `_id` in my created document, and using DocumentDB.Core my id is `id` in my created document. I'm not sure if that matters though, or how to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simillar issue you can take a look:

[Importing Json using DocumentDB Data Migration tool gives "Error while fetching page of documents code: 400" in CosmosDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594420/importing-json-using-documentdb-data-migration-tool-gives-error-while-fetching)

Further to understand,Below could be the reason for error code 400:-

-The JSON, SQL, or JavaScript in the request body is invalid.

-In addition, a 400 can also be returned when the required properties of a resource are not present or set in the body of the POST or PUT on the resource.

-400 is also returned when the consistent level for a GET operation is overridden by a stronger consistency from the one set for the account.

-400 is also returned when a request that requires an x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey does not include it.

Hope it helps.